# What would cause my PC to turn on when I flip the switch on the Power Supply?

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios, power-supply, amd-ryzen

So I started a new PC build with the Gigabyte B550 Vision D-P motherboard and the Ryzen 9 5950X CPU. The motherboard doesn't support the CPU out of the box, so I'm not getting any display. To resolve this, I have to download the latest BIOS update to USB and run the Q-FLASH PLUS to update the BIOS to support the CPU. The problem is this only works with the PC powered OFF.

- I've tried another power supply and it didn't help.
- I pulled out the CMOS battery for about 30 minutes and it didn't help.
- I do have the GPU, CPU, M2 SSDs and Liquid Cooler still installed.
- The only cables I have hooked up are the motherboard and CPU.
- When I had the power switches hooked up, they would not turn off the PC.

Surely someone has gone through this before and figured it out, because I have no clue.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance or ideas. **Just remember that I can't boot up.**

Thanks super users!

Comment: @ChanganAuto  https://youtu.be/X5EH9fDmgEc?t=253

Comment: Hook up the power switch and press it for 4 seconds, that should force it to power down.